# How to display the error message

Tags: jquery, validation

When I click the button I want to validate the fields and if there are any errors, I want to show user error message on top.

I am validating but I am not able to show the error message. Where exactly is the problem?.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
  var FirstName = $('#fName').val();
  alert(FirstName);
  var LastName = $('#lName').val();


  if (FirstName.val() == '') {
    $("#error").append("Please enter First Name");
  } else if (LastName.val() == '') {
    $("#error").append("Please enter Last Name");
  }
});
```

```html
<div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px;margin-top:21px">
  <p id="error"></p>
  <label for="text">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="fName">
  <label for="text">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="lName">
  <a href="" data-role="button" id="button" onclick="dtlsSubmit()">SUBMIT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
  var FirstName = $('#fName').val();
  var LastName = $('#lName').val();


  if (FirstName == '') {//remove .val()
    $("#fnameerror").show();
  } else if (LastName == '') {//remove .val()
    $("#lnameerror").show();
  }
});
```

```css
.error{
  
  display:none
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px;margin-top:21px">
  <p id="error"></p>
  <span id='fnameerror' class='error'>Please eneter First Name</span>
  <label for="text">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="fName">
  <span id='lnameerror' class='error'>Please eneter Last Name</span>
  <label for="text">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="lName">
  <a href="#" data-role="button" id="button" ">SUBMIT</a>
</div>
```

Add a span with error message then show if match the condition

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is because you set the `Firstname` and `Lastname` variables to the string values of the elements, then in the `if` conditions you attempt to again call `val()` on what is now a string, which will error as that method doesn't exist.

If there are no errors encountered (ie. all fields have a value) you can then call your `dtlsSubmit()` method from the jQuery event handler, like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link being followed
  var $error = $('#error').empty(); // remove any errors added on the previous click
  var error = false;
  
  if ($('#fName').val() == '') {
    error = true;
    $error.append("<p>Please enter First Name</p>");
  } 
  
  if ($('#lName').val() == '') {
    error = true;
    $error.append("<p>Please enter Last Name</p>");
  }

  if (!error) 
    dtlsSubmit();
});

function dtlsSubmit() {
    console.log('dtlsSubmit...');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px;margin-top:21px">
  <p id="error"></p>
  <label for="text">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="fName">
  <label for="text">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="lName">
  <a href="" data-role="button" id="button">SUBMIT</a>
</div>
```

Note that I amended the logic flow slightly so that *all* errors are shown on click of the `a`, instead of the first one encountered. This enables the user to know about all problems immediately and fix them without having to repeatedly click the button to find the next error.

Comment: I would preventDefault on an anchor in all cases - why not use a submit button

Comment: I was thinking the same - although I assumed the OP wanted to prevent the link being followed if the required fields were not completed as there is no `form` element in his code.

Comment: Ah - he wants to execute onclick="dtlsSubmit()"

Comment: That would seem like a logical assumption - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion - remove the inline click and put it in the validation

```js
function dtlsSubmit() {
  // here you can send the data
}
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
  var FirstName = $('#fName').val();
  var LastName = $('#lName').val();
  var error = "";
  if ($.trim(FirstName) == '') {
    error += "Please enter First Name<br/>";
  } 
  if ($.trim(LastName) == '') {
    error += "Please enter Last Name<br/>";
  }
  $("#error").html(error); // empty if no error
  if (error=="") {
    dtlsSubmit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px;margin-top:21px">
  <p id="error"></p>
  <label for="text">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="fName">
  <label for="text">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="lName">
  <a href="" data-role="button" id="button">SUBMIT</a>
</div>
```